# Getting Params structure seen in the input paramters of the Softmax Function from .tflite file

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

While looking through the [source code](https://github.com/tensorflow/tflite-micro/blob/a37043ff7a42e9d46345b4a6b33abda2fd1081f5/tensorflow/lite/kernels/internal/reference/softmax.h#L67) of Softmax, I'm curious about how to access the input parameter->'params' from the .tflite file.
Im interested in finding all the attributes and its value inside the params structure.
With the .tflite file that i have, is there a way i could get access to them?
Any sort of help is appreciated.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: You can upload the tflite model in [netron webapp](https://netron.app/) to see model architecture and details of all tensors. Another approach is to print all layers details through a for loop.

Answer (score 0):

The logic can be found in [this](https://github.com/tensorflow/tflite-micro/blob/a37043ff7a42e9d46345b4a6b33abda2fd1081f5/tensorflow/lite/micro/kernels/softmax_common.cc#L92) part (Note that this is tflite micro code base).

Just follow the logic on how the fields are computed from different bits of data.